# Как расшифровывается "начрайзо"?

Tags: значение-слов, сокращения

Начальник районного чего? Здравоохранения, что ли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Начальник районного чего?

Если поискать в гугло-книгах, то РайЗО в околовоенный период встречается двух вариантах: земельный отдел и здравоохранение. Документальность второго употребления у меня в том источнике вызвало сомнения, да и по контексту рассказа не подходит. Поэтому наиболее правдоподобный вариант ответа — районный земельный отдел.

[Здесь](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=eDrmAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT89&dq=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%BE%22%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBucjJt5PhAhWqtIsKHZ5VDdkQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B7%D0%BE%22%20%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&f=false), например, история в начале войны и даётся расшифровка "райзо (земельный отдел)".

Comment: Спасибо! Военного. Я встретил в рассказе Фёдора Гладкова "Маша из Заполья", где рассказывается о жизни в тылу как раз во время войны.

Comment: Спасибо, весёленький рассказ. Но я теперь думаю, что это не заготовительный, а земельный отдел. Сейчас откорректирую ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Интересно. Я рад, что Вам рассказ понравился. ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Однако директор Павловской **МТС** товарищ Рябец не организовал передачу опыта этой бригады всем остальным. Начальник **Райзо** товарищ Кендель уже планирует дать заключительную **сводку о парах** 5 июня...* (["Сталинский путь". 1937 год](http://kostanay1879.ru/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=2176&Itemid=48))

*После окончания института был направлен старшим мелиоратором Дедовичского **районного земельного отдела**... В январе 1940 г. К. Г. Тетерин назначен на должность заведующего **райзо** в Дедовичах* ([А. Федоров. Руководители Струго-Красненского района 1927—2017](https://books.google.ee/books?id=BWApDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT209&lpg=PT209&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%97%D0%9E&source=bl&ots=wTwBPfY6e5&sig=ACfU3U34jS4vutdS-APUkbmIP8Fxzu2SPw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiU5aHWkpThAhVokosKHaHdCdYQ6AEwDnoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%97%D0%9E&f=false)).

*Первое колхозное собрание в Нестеровском районе, состоявшееся 27 августа в посёлке Пеллютинен, провёл сам начальник гражданского управления В. И. Машин. На остальных председательствовали, как правило, заместитель по политической части (ранг будущего первого секретаря райкома) или **начальник РайЗО (Районный земельный отдел)**, а также и другие «представители района»* ([Ю. В. Костяшов. На колхозном собрании](https://ihistorian.wordpress.com/2009/11/28/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-i/)).

Другое сокращенное название — **райземотдел** — встречается гораздо чаще.

*Николай Артемьевич Никишев — «дядя Коля» — возглавил **райземотдел** Дубровского района, а потом стал председателем колхоза* (О. Горчаков, Я. Пшимановский).

*В апреле 1942 года **райземотдел** Выборгского района Ленинграда выделил институту земельный участок в районе Гражданки…* (С. Глезеров)

Comment: Спасибо, Римма Михайловна!